# Pure CSS menu - sub-menu disapears on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm working on pure CSS menu, and I don't know how to make sub-menu stay visible when I move out from the li element.

Height needs to be 100% of the page and sub-menu is identical as the main menu and it appears on the right.

Any advice would be most welcome!

Here is the demo (http://jsfiddle.net/91t43ruo/1/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sed id cursus</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Co-Investor</a></li>
      <li class="has-sub-menu"><a href="#">Donec interdum</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Ut quis bibendum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Praesent vestibulum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sed ultrices</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Morbi a mi blandit</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pellentesque</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

body, html{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    font-family:Arial;
}
a {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*Wrapper*/
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
/* Menu */
.main-menu, .sub-menu {
    background-color: #2F759B;
    width: 200px;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    padding: 20px;
}
.main-menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.main-menu li {
    color: white;
    background-color: #3585B0;
    line-height: 26px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.main-menu li:hover, .main-menu li.has-sub-menu{
    background-color: #43A8DD;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.main-menu a {
    color: inherit;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
/*Sub Menu*/
.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 240px;    
}
.sub-menu ul {
}
/*Hover*/
.main-menu li:hover > div.sub-menu{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Pure CSS menus are misguided. You will need JavaScript to make this menu keyboard accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's just too far from the `li` so there is a gap between the hover and the submenu. instead of  `left: 240px` on `.sub-menu` change it to `left: 220px;`

```
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 220px;  
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/91t43ruo/2/)

**UPDATE**

Ok my suggestion is to wrap the sub-menu in another `div` so it can still touch but have the spacing you want:

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/91t43ruo/4/)

Comment: That is great, thank you. I need to have padding on both sides. Your answer really fixes the hover problem but now the sub-menu is overlapping with the main menu.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/91t43ruo/5/)

```
.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 220px; /*Change 240px to 220px;*/ 
    padding-left: 40px; /**Add this**/
}
```